# Uploaded image not added as inline in text editor when custom block rendering is also added in React-draft-wyswyg

Tags: reactjs, wysiwyg, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I have a text editor created  using react-draft-wysiwyg. I have created a custom blockrendering function which enables in adding a custom block.

Editor code :

```
<Editor
    blockRenderMap={extendedBlockRenderMap}
    blockRendererFn={blockRendererFn}
    editorState={this.state.editorState}
    onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
    toolbarCustomButtons={[<FileAttachmentButton onAddFile={this.onAddFile} />]}
    toolbar={{
        options: ['inline', 'fontSize', 'fontFamily',
             'list', 'textAlign', 'colorPicker',
             'link', 'image'],
        link:{
            defaultTargetOption:'_blank',
            showOpenOptionOnHover:true
        },
        image:{
            urlEnabled: true,
            uploadEnabled:true,
            uploadCallback:this.uploadImageCallBack,
            alignmentEnabled: true,
            defaultSize: {
                height: 'auto',
                width: 'auto',
            }
        }
    }}
/>
```

RenderMap

```
const RenderMap = new Map({
  FileAttachment: {
    element: 'div'
  }
}).merge(DefaultDraftBlockRenderMap);
const extendedBlockRenderMap = DefaultDraftBlockRenderMap.merge(RenderMap);
```

BlockRendering function

```
function blockRendererFn(contentBlock) {
  const type = contentBlock.getType();
  if (type === 'FileAttachment') {
    return {
      component: FileAttachment,
      editable: false,
      props: {}
    };
  }
}
```

Image call back function

```
uploadImageCallBack(file){
    let uploadedImages = this.state.uploadedImages;
    const imageObject = {
      file: file,
      localSrc: URL.createObjectURL(file),
    }
    uploadedImages.push(imageObject);
    this.setState({uploadedImages: uploadedImages})
    return new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {
        resolve({ data: { link: imageObject.localSrc } });
      }
    )
}
```

Custom Block Rendering works as I expected. But when I include custom block rendering uploading image functionality isnt working properly.
Added image is not added inline.

When I try to add Image I am getting both atomic and FileAttachment as contentBlock type which might be restricting the image builtin functionality. When I inspected the content of the editor there is figure tag but there is no img tag attached to the figure tag

Can someone help me in figuring out a solution?

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution in the meantime ? I am struggling with the same issue